# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: option autoreconnect is not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb

## index.js file

```
 import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
    const DB_CONNECTION_URL =
      "mongodb+srv://user:<password>@cluster0.cjkjw.mongodb.net/WhatsAppDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    
    const connectDB = () => {
        console.log("DB trying to connect on " + new Date());
        const options = {
            keepAlive: 1,
            maxPoolSize: 10,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            autoReconnect: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        };
        return mongoose.connect(DB_CONNECTION_URL, options);
    };
    
    export default connectDB;
```

## eroor in my console

```
> whatsapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server
> node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --presets node8 ./server.js

DB trying to connect on Tue Nov 30 2021 21:31:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
(node:2944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: option autoreconnect is not supported
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongodb\src\connection_string.ts:358:11)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongodb\src\mongo_client.ts:327:34)
    at C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:779:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:776:19)
    at C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:332:10
    at C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\krish\onedrive\desktop\whatsapp_clone-mern_Stack\whatsapp-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1153:10)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2944) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i need to connect to my localhost when i run this it shows the above error. i used poolsize instead of maxPoolsize and it shows the same error showing poolsize is not supported but when searched for the solution it shows there is some updation for the version and the new version doesnt support poolsize so i changed to maxpoolsize and it works but i didnt found any answer for the autorecconet i hope there is also an update for autoReconnet in the new version . but when i remove the auto reconnet code it works!! please help me to fix this!

Comment: Did you find a solution for the  `MongoParseError: option autoreconnect is not supported` error?